# Database Design for Storing Seasons

Tags: database, database-design

We are building a travel App which will have destinations. We want to store which months of the year a particular place is good to visit. And we will be implementing a search pattern where a user can choose a month and we should be serving places which is best suited to travel during that month or months.

What i have tried ?

```
places(id, name, ....)

months (id, name)

places_months(id, place_id, month_id)
```

Is this the right approach or is there any smarter way to store and retrieve the same.

While Displaying the Months i would also like to show that From Jan to April this place is good to visit instead of Jan, Feb, March, April.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being "good to visit" during a particular month is (a) subjective and (b) not a binary decision.

I suggest your "desitnation quality by time table", which you call `places_months` be structured something like the following.  Note that I am suggesting a simple tiny int for month.  You don't need a code table just for month names.

```
create table places_months
(
  place_id int not null
, start_month tinyint not null
, end_month tinyint not null
, quality tinyint not null  -- Maybe a score from 0 to 5?
, comment varchar(100) null -- Reason why it is particularly bad (or good)
, constraint pk_places_months PRIMARY KEY (place_id,start_month)
, constraint ck_places_months CHECK (start_month<=end_month)
)
```

With a table like this you can give more nuanced answers.  If you still want to force some kind of binary decision you could always query based on `quality>=3` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of suggestions:

First (IMO) you should use a composite primary key on places_months, and lose the id column.  That ensures that you always have unique pairs of values.  And for the last request about ranges instead of a list of months: that can be done in php when you get the list of months for a given place.  This is a totally valid way of doing this.

Second (instead of the above) you could include ranges.  So for places_months, you would make the schema be the following:

```
id, place_id, start_month, end_month
0     1           3           5
1     1           8           8
```

That would mean at place_id 1 it is good from March-May and August.  That would facilitate your last request about displaying ranges (though this wouldn't be hard to do with php in either of the cases).

Just 2 suggestions.